# How to make a synchronous volley StringRequest?

Tags: android, mobile-application

How to make Volley StringRequest should wait for the one response to complete and after completing the first response it should start another request.

Comment: you actually wrote that in your question itself. you have to make another request  when you get the response from first one

Answer (score 1):

you have to do if your first response successfully then call these second method your answers is into your question

Answer (score 0):

Inside onResponse of your StringRquest make the second request you want.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, recieveMessageUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                //create second request here
                //and add it to queue 
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               
            }
        });
```

Note: you will have to make sure that your response is valid otherwise the onErrorResponse will be called.